'STR R0,[R0],#0X08' results in 'UNPREDICTABLE' behaviour?
why does the assembler says that the codeSTR R0,[R0],#0X08results in 'UNPREDICTABLE' behaviour?
source code:
    AREA MOV1,CODE,READONLY
    ENTRY
    CODE32
START
    MOV R0,#0X40000000
    MOV R2,#-0X02
    STR R0,[R0],#0X08
    LDR R1,[R0,R2,LSL #02]  
    END

error message:
Rebuild started: Project: 1
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 6 (build 750)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
Rebuild target 'Target 1'
assembling MOV1.s...
CODE\MOV1.s(7): error: A1477E: This register combination results in UNPREDICTABLE behaviour
".\Objects\1.axf" - 1 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:00

My own interpretation is that the content of R0 is going to be stored in memory,but the content of R0 is also going to be added by 8 as a result of post-indexed addressing mode,thus the conflict arises.Is it correct?

Yes, you are right. Since you are using post index addressing mode and using the same register for address and data, it will result in unpredictable behaviour.
